# What program can develop videos like ....?

Tags: video, video-editor

What program can develop videos like this one:

Comment: Oh, look, Papirus font.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any video editing package will do this. I'm pretty certain I could do it in Windows Movie Maker - there is nothing really happening here: a background image with some fade-ins and -outs.

Comment: I would say this was definitely made in Windows Movie Maker.